# ¿ Escalar una imagen y luego rotarla?

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c

Tengo una imagen png en un objeto. La imagen es un circulo relleno de un color. Quiero escalar el objeto mas alto que ancho para que parezca el circulo un ovalo. Al intentar escalar el objeto funciona bien pero luego si quiero rotar el ovalo un angulo no me lo hace.

Si en cambio hago el procedimiento primero rotar y luego escalar me lo hace bien.
¿ Porqué tengo que rotar antes que escalar ?

El código que no funciona es el siguiente:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = tempObjeto.transform;
transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, escalaAncho, escalaAlto);
transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, angulo);
tempObjeto.transform = transform;
```

Y el código que funciona es este:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = tempObjeto.transform;
transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, angulo);
transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, escalaAncho, escalaAlto);
tempObjeto.transform = transform;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probé ambos códigos y ambos realizan las transformaciones, pero hay que tener mucho cuidado por que el orden en que colocas las transformaciones afectan el resultado final.

Fíjate también en que la transformación de rotación se hace en radianes. Puede que estés ingresando algún ángulo cerrado como 90º (M_PI/2) o 180º (M_PI). La forma mas fácil de comprobarlo, es meter la transformación en un bloque de animación y ver el movimiento.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^{
    tempObjeto.transform = transform;
}];
```

Si quieres experimentar los resultados en el orden de las transformaciones, te dejo este código que realiza la transformación e imprime las dimensiones finales. Es cosa de cambiar el orden de la rotación y escalado y compruebes lo que te tira la consola.

```
UIView* targetView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
targetView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:targetView];

CGAffineTransform transform = targetView.transform;
transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 0.5f);
transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.2f, 1.5f);
targetView.transform = transform;

NSLog(@"frame %@ bounds %@", NSStringFromCGRect(targetView.frame), NSStringFromCGRect(targetView.bounds));

UIView* backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:targetView.frame];
backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
[self.view insertSubview:backgroundView atIndex:0];
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta !